# Cassandra commands over network

Tags: c, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

Hi i am new to Cassandra. Can anyone please tell me how Cassandra queries are transfered over network like i have a C program to do all the queries in one network and Cassandra database in another network. Is there anything to be modified in .yaml file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to open port (9042) from app server to cassandra server... if not opened

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation open port 9042 for cql and 9160 for thrift 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureFireWall.html